# Is it possible to pass custom data to stripe checkout?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm following the documentation for Stripe Checkout with server integration: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server

The code in the examples works fine, but the problem I'm having is being unable to track the user, or their order, when a purchase is complete.

I have a webhook setup that Stripe pings when a payment is complete. But the response session from Stripe contains no information about the product ordered except for it's name, description, and image. I could use the product name to query the database but I'd much rather an ID, or a slug, of sorts.

```
$app->post("/stripe-pingback", function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxxx");

    // You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
    $endpoint_secret = 'xxxxx';

    $payload = $request->getBody();
    $sig_header = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'] : null;
    $event = null;

    try {
        $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent($payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret);
    } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        // Invalid payload
        http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
        exit();
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
        // Invalid signature
        http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
        exit();
    }

    // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if ($event->type == 'checkout.session.completed') {
        $session = $event->data->object;
        var_dump($session);

        // Possible to get custom data from session?
        $customer = $session->customer;
        $customerEmail = $session->customer_email;

        // Fulfill the purchase...
        $this->db->insertAudioPurchase();
    }

    http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
});
```

Is it possible to pass an ID along with the checkout request that Stripe can ping back to allow me to lookup the order and generate a download link?

Comment: Seriously, I can't understand why the most important data you expect to know from a checkout session, like "what did my user pay for", is left to additional flows or workarounds by Stripe.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit:** `metadata` now *does* [exist on the Session object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata). Although you will probably need to be on a more recent API version to be able to set it.

`metadata` doesn't exist on the Session object yet, so you can't use that.

You can use the `client_reference_id` field to store some custom data in your Session. Just be aware that the contents has to be unique. [Have a look here.](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-client_reference_id)

Comment: Thanks. This poses a problem as I have no unique ID for the customer. The purchase process doesn't require reg. and only requires an email address that the user provides on the stripe checkout. Maybe generate an ID by encrypting the data with a key, and decrypt it on checkout success to get the required information for the purchase?

Comment: I was overthinking it. I can put the product slug in there.

Comment: Stripe 'Session' now has a metadata property: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata. Strangely, assigned metadata does NOT appear in the Stripe web admin interface, but it DOES come back to my webhook.

Comment: In what webhook can you see it? I tried on the payment_intent.succeeded without any success.

Comment: `payment_intent.succeeded` describes a PaymentIntent. You likely want `checkout.session.completed`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed

Comment: I can see the metadata property from a `checkout.session.completed` event. Besides appearing in a webhook, it also appears in the Stripe web admin interface under Payments->click on a payment->Events and Logs section->make sure an "A Checkout Session was completed" event from the activity chain is selected->Event Data

Comment: we can see metadata on Dashboard - > Payments -> Detail 
if it is added Like this  

            "payment_intent_data"=>['metadata' => [
                'order_id' => '12345',
                'customer_notes' => 'Please deliver to my office.'
            ]],

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if you've found the solution but that's the mine.
I have used payment intent data and insert into this metadata, that's one of my first help on stackoverflow.
I'm searching from two 2 days the solution, and that's it. So i want to help you.

Stripe Docs are not so clearly and useful

```
                    payment_intent_data: {
                        metadata: {
                            key1 : val1,
                            ke2  : val2,
                            key3 : val3,
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: simple and clear

Answer (score 5):

You can pass an array with key `metadata`. Stripe will return this field as you've sent when payment is complete.

You just have to pass as this format.

```
"metadata": {}
```

Although, I used it for creating user and saving cards. However, I didn't use it at the time of checkout, but it seems you can pretty much pass this with every API.

From [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata),

> Updateable Stripe objects—including Account, Charge, Customer, PaymentIntent, Refund, Subscription, and Transfer—have a metadata parameter. You can use this parameter to attach key-value data to these Stripe objects.
>
> **Metadata is useful for storing additional, structured information on an object.** As an example, you could store your user's full name and corresponding unique identifier from your system on a Stripe Customer object. Metadata is not used by Stripe—for example, not used to authorize or decline a charge—and won't be seen by your users unless you choose to show it to them.

Comment: It looks as though you can't, according to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744094/stripe-checkout-wont-accept-metadata

Comment: In fact you can. But you will need to use the session.PaymentIntentData.Metadata field, not session.Metadata

Comment: @Softlion thank you! I was struggling for a day and received only empty metadata.

Answer (score 4):

```
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            customer_email='foo@bar.bar',
            success_url=domain_url + 'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=domain_url + 'cancel/',
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='subscription',
            locale='pl',
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price': 'price_*****************',
                    'quantity': 1,
                }
            ],
            subscription_data={'metadata':{'someKeyHere': 'your session variable data'}}
        )
```

[image: stripe dashboad now shows metadataenter code here]

Answer (score 0):

Metadata can be placed in different areas. It depends on the use case and where you want to access it.

If you want the metadata to be attached to the **payment inten**t (related to the whole checkout), use `payment_intent_data.metadata`. If you want to attach the metadata to a **specific line item** or product, use `product_data.metadata`.

See the example below which contains **both use cases:**

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    ui_mode: 'embedded',
    line_items: [
        {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'gbp',
                product_data: {
                    name: 'Name',
                    description: 'Description',
                    // PRODUCT metadata
                    metadata: {
                        product_meta_key: 'product_meta_value'
                    }
                },
                unit_amount: 2000,
            },
            quantity: 1,
        },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    return_url: `...`,
    payment_intent_data: {
        // PAYMENT metadata
        metadata: {
            payment_intent_key: 'payment_intent_value',
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return {
      price_data: {
        
        currency: "inr",
        product_data: {
        name: item.name,
        metadata : { //passing extra data here
          id : item.id
        } 
        },
        unit_amount: item.price*100,
      },
      quantity: item.quantity,
     
    };
  })
```

You can pass the ID like this.