# Stripe checkout wont accept metadata

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe checkout (the latest version) and need to send additional data so I can reconcile a later webhook.

Stripe rejects the metadata with the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Received unknown parameter: metadata'
```

My partially redacted code looks like this

```
$object = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'success_url' => 'www/payment_processor.php?action=success',
    'cancel_url' => 'www/payment_processor.php?action=cancel',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'customer_email' => $email,
    'metadata' => ['user_id' => $user_id],
    'line_items' => [[
        'amount' => $amount,
        'currency' => $currency,
        'name' => 'Purchase',
        'description' => $description,
        'quantity' => 1,
    ]]
]);
```

I expect the metadata to be accepted and returned with the webhook, as described in the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata).

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. It would be handy to be able to add some sort of ID to the items.

Comment: In the end I added the property - client_reference_id and used a comma separated list of values. The only issue is that the client_reference_id is only returned for a completed checkout session, and not a charge success event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First sentence of the linked documentation states:

> Updateable Stripe objects—including **Account, Charge, Customer, PaymentIntent, Refund, Subscription, and Transfer** —have a metadata parameter.

You are creating neither of those, you are creating a **Session**

**Update**
As Oliver Dixon pointed out, Stripe Sessions now do have a [meta data property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-metadata) (although they are still not stated in the [meta data article](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata))

Comment: I understand. Thanks. How they can someone reconcile a transaction processed by Stripe with a customer on my site. It seems this would be a commonly needed action.

Comment: If I understood your comment right you are might looking for the *client_reference_id* property of the session object: "A unique string to reference the Checkout Session. This can be a customer ID, a cart ID, or similar, and can be used to reconcile the session with your internal systems."

Comment: Downvotes as this just points out that it should not work without providing a solution which user13688383 did in his anwser below.

Comment: @MarkusKnappenJohansson Technically speaking, OP didn't ask anything specific, therefore there can not be a definitive solution. I pointed out that a session does not accept meta data as OP expected, therefore clarifying the problem.

Comment: When creating a session, metadata should be as follows:           payment_intent_data: {
                metadata: {platform: (data.platform || 'unsure')}
            }

Comment: Sessions now support metadata, for anyone reading.

Comment: @OliverDixon According to Stripe's support team, sessions have a Metadata object, but that object will not be passed to the server or back to the client in the response. It's not currently supported yet.

Comment: Actually, to make it work, we must also pass a `client_reference_id`

Answer (score 19):

For anyone still coming across this issue, simply placing a `client_reference_id` or `metadata` parameter did not work for me even with the 2020-08-27 API.

Adding `payment_intent_data` with metadata is what got it to work for me. You can try adding the following code:

```
'payment_intent_data'=>['metadata' => ["order_id" => $orderID, "type" => "myProduct"],
```

Comment: Yes but this only works for ``payment`` mode

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. After creating a session the data is not in there and there's no `payment_intent_data` property. The data isn't returned in the response after session completion either.

Comment: Update: I do see the metadata in the Stripe console when viewing the Payment Intent.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this

```
stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_intent_data: {
        application_fee_amount: this.booking_fee,
        metadata: {
            key1 : value1,
            key2 : value2,
            .
            .
            key N : value N
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: it's cool you can, I can't seem to get this to work. Stripe keeps rejecting with "empty metadata" claims even though the metadata property is clearly a json

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

You cannot attach metadata to a `Session`, but you *can* attach metadata to either the `payment_intent` or `setup_intent` that will be created in the session.

See [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata), you pass it as `payment_intent_data.metadata`.

Note that Stripe [warns you](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) not to put sensitive data in `metadata`, so if you want to store a client name etc, you're better off putting it in a database under a unique key and then pass the key as `client_reference_id`.

Comment: adding metadata to payment intent shows the metadata in the web UI - adding metadata to the actual payment does not show it

Answer (score 5):

As of October 2020 the session object has metadata.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to return it properly.
However passing it through `payment_intent_data.metadata` works. Or maybe it's just me.

Comment: it's not only you. setting the `metadata` to session will only return it when `checkout.session.completed` event gets triggered.

Comment: ^ Thanks @BinarWeb. That explains it.

Comment: @BinarWeb It doesn't get returned even for the checkout completed event, nor does it show in the dashboard when looking at the logs.

Comment: Update: the session's metadata seems to get put onto the charge's metadata and saved there.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct that `metadata` doesn't exist on the Session object.  `client_reference_id` is an alternative but it has to be unique and it must be a string.

If you just want metadata to show up on the purchase in the Stripe Dashboard, use the `payment_intent_data` attribute when creating your session.  That's how you attach metadata to a purchase made during a session.  [Relevant documentation here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata).

Answer (score 2):

The Stripe Session object does not accept `metadata` as a parameter. [See here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) for the details.

The [reference you give](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) in your question is for a Stripe ***Charge***  object which *does* accept metadata.

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and came across the need to bundle some information for example customer id, order id etc, across over to stripe. There's a parameter called *payment_intent_data* which is an associative array. Within payment_intent_data you have a property called *description* which you can use to embed some extra information. The description you put here will show up on the description field when you do a csv payment export on stripe.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-description

```
              $stripe_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
              'submit_type' => 'pay',
              'billing_address_collection' => 'required',
              'customer' => $customer,            
              'client_reference_id' => $customer ,
              'payment_intent_data'=>['description' =>'This is my description'],
              'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
              'line_items' => [[
                'name' => $event->title,
                'description' => $description/*This description does not go on csv export, it's more or less cosmetic */,               
                'amount' => ($fee),
                'currency' => 'gbp',
                'quantity' => 1,
              ]],
              'success_url' => 'example.com',
              'cancel_url' => 'example.com',
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Metadata must be **nested** in the Session creation object:

Stripe's docs incorrectly list metadata as a parent (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) when in fact it's a child:

https://support.stripe.com/questions/using-metadata-with-checkout-sessions

1. payment_intent_data.metadata
2. subscription_data.metadata

client_reference_id is associated with the Session only, and does not get stored in Stripe as metadata.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Stripe support, and this was their response.

> Thank you for writing in. I understand that you were trying to send a
> Metadata when creating a Checkout Session using the API. I'll be glad
> to check this for you.
>
> Upon checking, the new Checkout does not currently support Metadata
> unfortunately. [...]
>
> Since the API Documentation seem to be confusing, I'll have this
> checked by our product team, to update and check the said
> documentation.

And another response:

> Just a bit of context, metadata that is set on an object will not be
> silently copied over to any associated objects that are created at the
> same time. When a PaymentIntent is confirmed, we do a one-time copy of
> the PaymentIntent’s metadata (as well as some other fields) over to
> the Charge. It is important to note that this is a one-time copy - for
> example any subsequent updates to the PaymentIntent’s metadata are not
> synced to the Charge object (or vice-versa) and would need to be
> explicitly copied over by you with additional API requests.
>
> If you want to set metadata on the PaymentIntent specifically you have
> to set here:
>
> https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata
>
> Using the method described in your question, should persist but only
> in the checkout session flow. It would not be present on any other
> events (namely charge, PaymentIntent, or other flows).

I still didn't really understand how to get the metadata working how I wanted it to, but I found that the `client_reference_id` parameter worked well enough for me.