# Cannot add Metadata to payment intent in Stripe

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am developing an app. Part of this app is to pay for courses into a connected stripe account that is managed by the app.

That part is working very well.

I am now trying to find a way to filter the payments by `course_id`. My idea is to put the course id in the `payment_intent_metadata`. That way I can fetch all payments by connected account and then filter the list locally by `metadata.course_id`.

I've got the following code that creates the checkout session and attaches the course_id:

```
private async createCheckout(
    p: IResponseData<Participant>,
    input: supportParticipantInput,
    courseId: string
  ) {
    //create checkout
    return await this.stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      success_url: input.redirect,
      cancel_url: input.redirect,
      mode: 'payment',
      payment_method_types: simpleConfig.payment_method_types,
      customer_email: input?.supporterEmail,
      payment_intent_data: {
        metadata: {
        course_id: courseId,
        },
        description: 'testdescription',
        transfer_data: {
          destination: p.attributes.stripeAccountId,
        },
      },
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            currency: 'eur',
            product_data: {
              name: 'support Participant2',
            },
            unit_amount: input.amount,
          },
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
```

According to the stripe documentation at
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create this should work.

I've tried a lot and can't seem to find the mistake. Hopefully someone here knows something I could try/change

UPDATE
Thats what is beeing return by calling the method:

````
{
  "id": "cs_test_a1FXQhJ9ap2rn5Yb5itXvj6JHUq6L6p78jq4q0fzd3N30UkZa6NYohg4Mz",
  "object": "checkout.session",
  "after_expiration": null,
  "allow_promotion_codes": null,
  "amount_subtotal": 15000,
  "amount_total": 15000,
  "automatic_tax": {
    "enabled": false,
    "status": null
  },
  "billing_address_collection": null,
  "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "client_reference_id": "2",
  "client_secret": null,
  "consent": null,
  "consent_collection": null,
  "created": 1700067702,
  "currency": "eur",
  "currency_conversion": null,
  "custom_fields": [],
  "custom_text": {
    "shipping_address": null,
    "submit": null,
    "terms_of_service_acceptance": null
  },
  "customer": null,
  "customer_creation": "if_required",
  "customer_details": null,
  "customer_email": null,
  "expires_at": 1700154101,
  "invoice": null,
  "invoice_creation": {
    "enabled": false,
    "invoice_data": {
      "account_tax_ids": null,
      "custom_fields": null,
      "description": null,
      "footer": null,
      "metadata": {},
      "rendering_options": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "locale": null,
  "metadata": {
    "test": "1"
  },
  "mode": "payment",
  "payment_intent": null,
  "payment_link": null,
  "payment_method_collection": "always",
  "payment_method_configuration_details": null,
  "payment_method_options": {},
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card",
    "sofort",
    "klarna"
  ],
  "payment_status": "unpaid",
  "phone_number_collection": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "recovered_from": null,
  "setup_intent": null,
  "shipping_address_collection": null,
  "shipping_cost": null,
  "shipping_details": null,
  "shipping_options": [],
  "status": "open",
  "submit_type": null,
  "subscription": null,
  "success_url": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "total_details": {
    "amount_discount": 0,
    "amount_shipping": 0,
    "amount_tax": 0
  },
  "ui_mode": "hosted",
  "url": "https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1FXQhJ9ap2rn5Yb5itXvj6JHUq6L6p78jq4q0fzd3N30UkZa6NYohg4Mz#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0SWh9fHNNcHRzVl1jbm1Qc3NjfFRoPGd1bG53N1x8fERwSGZQYWZqTF1HbDZCMTVSRz1IX3VfPG1waHVyUT1EcXxdSn9vc21BYVBMc2NhT3ZjaWBRYTJGNTVTTVZ0bj1RaicpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl"
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a "newer" feature (or at least the documentation is in flux), and looking at various sources/online discussions, it looks like to get it to work, you must also pass a `client_reference_id` which is listed in the docs as a [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object).

Please try something like the following - please note, I used your entry and added a placeholder piece of data, please fit to your needs.  Note the comments in the code which you can remove:

```
private async createCheckout(
    p: IResponseData<Participant>,
    input: supportParticipantInput,
    courseId: string
  ) {
    //create checkout
    return await this.stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      // ! added this string to your session, please fit to your needs
      client_reference_id: courseId,
      //^ ! added this string to your session, please fit to your needs
      success_url: input.redirect,
      cancel_url: input.redirect,
      mode: 'payment',
      payment_method_types: simpleConfig.payment_method_types,
      customer_email: input?.supporterEmail,
      payment_intent_data: {
        metadata: {
        course_id: courseId,
        },
        description: 'testdescription',
        transfer_data: {
          destination: p.attributes.stripeAccountId,
        },
      },
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            currency: 'eur',
            product_data: {
              name: 'support Participant2',
            },
            unit_amount: input.amount,
          },
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
    });
  }
```

Also, point 2: Make sure you're looking at the right place to see if it's working.  AFAIK the session's metadata gets put on the charge's metadata and saved there.  (And not in the checkout complete event nor at the dashboard when looking at the logs.)

H/T to the respondents of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744094/stripe-checkout-wont-accept-metadata?rq=3) in PHP.  Check out that question, and especially at the responses and comments around 2023.

Comment: i´ve tried that, but still i do not receive any metadata in the dashboard on my payments or when i fetch the charges via the api

Comment: After you go through checkout and pay, can you show the charge info? (feel free to obscure any real data as you need to but would like to see what you received on the charge info and before and after the above ^ change would be ideal )

Comment: I added whats returned into the question

Comment: I'm looking for charge's metadata.  I believe you wrote checkout.session data.  Also, I see the status is unpaid, please makes sure when you post the charge's metadata you add it after the payment.

Comment: where exactly do I find that .. im not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is definitely correct. You are passing `payment_intent_data[metadata]` to control this. The resulting PaymentIntent that will be created will definitely have that metadata information on it automatically set.

If you go through Checkout and pay, you will get a resulting PaymentIntent that has the right metadata